# Two jQuery plugin conflicting on the same page

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, conflict, conflicting-libraries

I have two jQuery Plugins working on the same file. One is `jquery.autocomplete.js` and the other is `jquery.thumbnailScroller.js` .

The problem is when I am using both on same file, autocomplete is not working at all an thumbnailScroller is working and but the same is working well without thumbnailScroller plugin.

Now, when I was browsing thru the js files, I got `$.fn.` in both files. But, I dont know is the problem because of this or anything else.

I had searched in google and stackoverflow also, but I failed to get the proper solution.
Please guide me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some ways for avoiding conflict in jquery.
I always do like this

```
var $k = jQuery.noConflict();
```

and use $k for every $ functions for any one plugin. Not do this in plugin js files. Do this for your implementation page, like,

```
$k("#id").autocomplete({...
```

Regards

iijb