# how to prevent conflict beetween two jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have two jquery plugin
Image Picker [link](http://rvera.github.io/image-picker/) and select2 [link](https://select2.github.io/)
when i use the both of this plugin one of them is cannot run
here is my code

jquery code

```
$(".select2").select2();
$(".imagepicker").imagepicker();
```

select menu for select2

```
<select class="select2">
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

select menu for imagepicker

```
<select class="imagepicker">
  <option data-img-src="img/01.png" value="1">  Page 1  </option>
  <option data-img-src="img/02.png" value="2">  Page 2  </option>
  <option data-img-src="img/03.png" value="3">  Page 3  </option>
</select>
```

I don't know what is happening, but when I use the both of this plugin one of them is not working, maybe because in same select tag?

I am sorry my english is bad

Comment: Typo? `.selec2();` => `.select2();`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743578/two-jquery-plugin-conflicting-on-the-same-page this might help you

Comment: now is corrected, sorry

Comment: @RinoRaj It's not working, please help me T-T

Answer (score 0):

The thumb rule is that your last plugin loaded would overrun the previous segment.